# How to get friends' location using Facebook Graph API v2.2

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve friends' location using the Facebook Graph API v2.2 but only getting basic friend info (id, name) but not location. I tried adding the location field but still friends location not showing up.

Here is the call I executed on Graph Explorer

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/friends?fields=location

Also is it possible to retrieve friends' network or filter friends list by location or current city?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's simply not possible anymore since Graph API v2.0. All the `friends_*` permissions have been removed.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: Is there any other way to bring `friends_location` or `friends_hometown`?

Comment: This is unfortunate!  Every other tech giant in the world feels like being Big Brother, so why doesn't Facebook?  Had a cool app idea only to be disappointed by this!

Comment: facebook still has that info so they still can play big brother. third parties don't